# Referring to OTHER cells in relation to CURRENT cell in loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a data document i'm working on but some things on it are wrong so i need to overwrite specific cells automatically. I'm looking to set up a loop that goes through each cell in `column G` and if a certain value is present then insert a formula into the cell in the same row but in `column J`. I've got as far as setting up the loop but I don't know how to put the formula in the new cell and relate it to the current cell. I was thinking R[]C[] formulas may be the way to go but think this becomes confusing when the formula in not straightforward e.g VLOOKUPS with IFs and MATCHES etc...

```
Sub FindDefects()

    Dim RngCl As Range
    Dim Rngg As Range

    Set Rngg = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

    For Each RngCl In Rngg.Cells
        If RngCl.Value = "TEXT" Then
            RngCl.Offset(0,3).FormulaR1C1 = "R[0]C[-1]/R[0]C[3]"
        Else
            'Nada
        End If
    Next RngCl

End Sub
```

I'm not sure really where to go from here, especially how to add in formulas such as:

```
=IF(LEN(J9)>0,J9*VLOOKUP(M9,Core!A:C,3,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(K9,Core!A:C,3,FALSE),P9)
```

Instead of R1C1 formulas. Any help on moving forward is appreciated!

Comment: Not shure of what you want to achieve. But maybe you can try something like `RngCl.Offset(0, 3) = Sheet.Cells(RngCl.Row, RngCl.Column-1) / Sheet.Cells(RngCl.Row, RngCl.Column-3)`. Watch out that in your example (since Range is A1:A6) there is no `Column-1` or `Column-3`

Comment: Hi, CMArg, Thanks for the input, I thought the upside of using R1C1 Format was that it goes from the active cell, so you can reference cells "behind" the current one using R[-1]C[-1] per say.